# Invokation of principal constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

The Standard defines three kinds of constructors:

```
— delegating constructor
— target constructor
— principal constructor
```

12.6.2/6:

> The principal constructor is the first constructor invoked in the
>   construction of an object (that is, ***not*** a target constructor for that
>   object’s construction)

But the same section says:

> Once the target constructor returns, the body of the delegating
>   constructor is executed

Since, a target constructor and a delegating constructor cannot be a principal constructor. So what one is? I would like to consider that by example:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(int a)
    {
        cout << A::a << endl;
        A::a = a;
    }

    A(int a, int b)
    {
        cout << A::a << endl;
        A::a = a + b;
    }

    A() : A(10,10)
    {
        cout << "A()" <<endl;
    }
};

A a; //Subsequence of constructor's body execution is A(int, int) --> A()

int main()
{
    cout << a.a << endl;
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/15pSKs)

What is a principal in the example?

Comment: Besides you using `A::a` like it was a static member variable, you're printing it out before you initialize it, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: In your code `A()` is the principal constructor and `A(10, 10)` is the target constructor. `A()` is also a delegating constructor.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't agree. Actually, consider the quote from the section 9.3.1/3: `[...] if either the id-expression is potentially evaluated or C is X or a base class of X, the id-expression is transformed into a class member access expression (5.2.5) using (*this) (9.3.2) as the postfix-expression to the left of the . operator.`

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I'm not saying that using `A::a` is wrong, just that it's odd to use it that way, especially inside the class member functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh ,sorry. I didn't understand you. You're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you have

```
struct A
{
    ...

    A(int a, int b)
    {
        ...
    }

    A() : A(10,10) // A() is a delegating constructor and A(int,int) is the target constructor
    {
        ...
    }
};

A a;
```

This means `A()` is the delegating constructor, `A(int,int)` is the target constructor.

The standard says (N3690 §12.6.2 - 6)

> The principal constructor is the first constructor invoked in the
>   construction of an object (that is, not a target constructor for that
>   object’s construction).

this means `A()` is both a principal and delegating constructor in your example and that `A(int,int)`, since it's called by a delegating constructor, it's a target constructor and it **cannot** be a principal constructor.

---

**TL;DR** (as suggested by pqnet):

```
principal  -> the one you invoke
delegating -> the one which calls another constructor
target     -> the one that is called by another constructor
```

As an unrelated sidenote I agree with Joachim: you're default-initializing a nonstatic member variable and printing its value through scope resolution before its initialization. That is undefined behavior.

Comment: tl;dr: `principal` -> the one you invoke, `delegating` -> the one which calls another constructor, `target` -> the one that is called by another constructor

Comment: It seems out of topic, but I think there is no undefined behavior: "Zero initialization is performed [...] For every named variable with static [...] storage duration, before any other initialization [...] The constructors, if any, are ignored" (quote from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization))

Comment: That is, initially we invoke a principal constructor. If it is non-delegating constructor, the intialization is performed as specified in 12.6.2/8. Otherwise, we first invoke target constructor.

Comment: One more clarification. Is it specified in the standard when compiler determines is invoked contructor delegating or not? I mean, it determines during principal constructor invokation, or earlier at compile-time?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Do you mean the order for a principal and delegating constructor? The delegating constructor has its target constructor called before being able to initialize its own stuff

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    struct A
    {
        A() : A( 10 ) {}
        A( int x ) : A( x, 20 ) {}
        A( int x, int y ) : x( x ), y( y ) {}
        int x, y;
    };

    A a;

    std::cout << "a.x = " << a.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a.y = " << a.y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this example constructor A() is a delegating constructor. It calls constructor A( int ) that in turn also a delegating constructor that calls constructor A( int, int ).

In the definition

```
A a;
```

the first constructor that is invoked is A(). It is the principal constructor for this definition because it is called first. That is "The principal constructor is the **first constructor invoked
in the construction of an object"**"

If you add one more definition to the body of main as for example

```
A a2( 5 );
```

then for this definition the principal constructor is A( int ).

You made a wrong conclusion that a delegating constructor can not be a principal constructor. The first delegating constructor in the chain of delegating constructors is the principal constructor.

Comment: That is, implemetation determines whether a specific constructor is delegating during invokation of the one.

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv It determines whether a specific constructor is a principal constructor.